# URL forwarding with modrewrite in an htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm currently in the process of adapting my .htaccess file, but need help.

The URLs should all be redirected.

The big characters should be converted into small characters.
If the called address exists, the file should be called directly.
All other addresses that do not exist should be forwarded to Index.php.

The following link is now called:

- `www.example.com/test1/test2/test3.html`
- `example.com/TeST1/TEST2/test3.html`
- `www.example.com/test1/test2/test3`

The forwarding should always call the Index.php and the following should be in the address line:
`http://example.com/test1/test2/test3.html`

If I have variables (`example.com/TeST1/TEST2/test3.html?id=6&test=hello`) these should of course also be transferred.

So that my CSS files and images can be properly integrated, I think I have to deactivate the forwarding for certain file types.
The following folders should be excluded from the redirection: css, media, img

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f   
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L,QSA]
```

Can someone write the file or help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*[A-Z].*) /${lc:$1} [R=302,L]
# if you encounter double slashes, remove the slash before ${lc...

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help. Unfortunately, the code somehow doesn't work properly. I should look for the error in the log file. But there is nothing there. I use a subdomain. can this lead to dedm errors? The other code worked partially.